# Request for further explanation on a specific triage queue audit I failed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-audit

I just got (and failed) a triage queue audit for this question: [How does one create a cube with Julia and Makie?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74709648/11107541), which seems to be asking how to make a graphic for a shape. It shows an example of a shape graphic, and asks for something that (from the description) sounds very different than the graphic that they show.

I thought the question was vague in its description of what it *actually* wanted the shape to look like (and there's the problem: it's especially confusing when the graphic that they show is quite different from what they are describing that they want)

So I attempted to comment: "Either provide an image of what you want the result to look like, or provide the math and ask for the code to 'do that math'." I didn't notice when I tried to post the comment that the comment failed to post (probably with the message that it was an audit). I was a bit in the flow of things. Then I voted "needs author edit -> needs details/clarity". I failed the audit.

I thought my review (that it needed detail/clarity) made sense, because the accepted answer starts by *asking* "*Like this?*"? (If the asker provided the information I attempted to solicit via commenting, the answerer would not be providing an answer which is admittedly *guessing* what the asker wants) And then shows a graphic and corresponding code for something that matches their description (but is not the only possible graphic that could match their description).

Was I wrong in my judgement? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really see an issue with the question.  It's a bit densely packed in there, but everything we care about is there:

- A clear statement of what is needed to be accomplished
- An indication of what was attempted
- Examples pointing to what their desired state is

In this context I don't know what else the OP could *add* to this question, realistically.  As in...even if I wanted more information (which is my usual wont), I don't know what else I'd be asking for.

In a situation like this, if I were just completely *unsure* of myself, I'd rather skip this review instead.  I tend to view graphics questions as a bit of a slightly different beast, and as long as the OP isn't just dumping requirements on us, it's not the end of the world.

But in this case I just can't find anything particularly *wrong* with the question.

...Okay, *maybe* an argument could be made about this being "overly" broad:

> However, I would like to eliminate the holes, and also make the cube nearer the shape of an actual cube, with only slightly rounded corners and edges.

...but I feel like the ["almost" rule from Horseshoes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/389003) would be fine here, depending on one's expertise with drawing shapes.

Comment: huh! I didn't see the link to the example images. Well, we can close this as a case of me being blind and careless :P Thanks!

Comment: @starball Ideally the examples should be in the question itself, not hidden behind a link, so I wouldn't say it was careless of you not to check the link. In this case though, I think the question is clear enough without the link. If it were *only* "I need this: (link)" you would have been right to vote to close, but in this case I think the part in bold and the screenshot make it clear enough.

Answer (score 6):

Though I'm not familiar with the technologies used, the question seems perfectly clear to me.

The question asks for a shape *other* than the one depicted in the screenshot, and describes it pretty clearly: a "cube nearer the shape of an actual cube, with only slightly rounded corners and edges". Additionally, there is a [link with images of the shape](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/three-rounded-box) for those who need a visual. The title seems suboptimal, but can be easily improved ("a *rounded* cube").

The answer does not read like a guess to me. The first line seems to be an invitation for OP to check out the answer. It flows better than just starting with the code.

Comment: I didn't see the link to the examples. It can be chalked up to me rushing and being careless. Case closed! Thanks for taking the time to look at this :)